# When an Adjective Is Used with “Kept” (and Possibly Other Participles?), Does It Become an Adverb?

Tags: adjectives, adverbs, parts-of-speech

In phrases with “kept” (and perhaps there are other participles that have the same effect?), such as:

> He kept it secret.

> It was kept hidden.

Do these (nominal) adjectives function effectively as adverbs?  Could they be called proper adverbs in these instances?

They are all clearly adjectives, yet in these examples, they all answer the questions:

> How did he keep it? *(He kept it secret.)*

> How was it kept? *(It was kept hidden.)*

That is, these adjectives all function as adverbs because they describe the action of the verb “to keep”, i.e. they can answer a “how” question (in this case) or could be stated as “kept in a X way”—is this a correct assertion?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146711/discussion-on-question-by-avana-vana-when-an-adjective-is-used-with-kept-and); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.